# How to make an API to UDF API to use in tradingView Chart

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api

I'm using the trading view Chart. I've run it local. Now I want to use my own data via an API. But I know the trading view Chart works with UDF API. And I don't know how to make my API to UDF API. Can you help me?

This is my api (you can run it on Postman to see the response) : https://www.moneygain.com.vn/api/v1/history/HPG?interval=1D&from=2022-01-01&to=2022-11-08

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>TradingView Charting Library demo</title>

        <!-- Fix for iOS Safari zooming bug -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="charting_library/charting_library.standalone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script> -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getParameterByName(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
                var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                    results = regex.exec(location.search);
                return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }

            function initOnReady() {
                var datafeedUrl = "https://demo-feed-data.tradingview.com";
                var customDataUrl = getParameterByName('dataUrl');
                if (customDataUrl !== "") {
                    datafeedUrl = customDataUrl.startsWith('https://') ? customDataUrl : `https://${customDataUrl}`;
                }
                // datafeedUrl = "https://www.moneygain.com.vn/api/v1/history/from=2022-01-01&to=2022-11-08"

                var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
                    debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
                    fullscreen: true,
                    symbol: 'AAPL',
                    interval: '1D',
                    container: "tv_chart_container",

                    //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
                    datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(datafeedUrl),
                    library_path: "charting_library/",
                    locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",

                    disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
                    enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
                    charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
                    charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
                    client_id: 'tradingview.com',
                    user_id: 'public_user_id',
                    theme: getParameterByName('theme'),
                });
            };

            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initOnReady, false);
        </script>

    </head>

    <body style="margin:0px;">
        <div id="tv_chart_container"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you API should be in the format that can be read by tradingview charting library -

Request: GET `/history?symbol=<ticker_name>&from=<unix_timestamp>&to=<unix_timestamp>&resolution=<resolution>&countback=<countback>`

symbol: symbol name or ticker.
from: unix timestamp (UTC) of leftmost required bar
to: unix timestamp (UTC) of rightmost required bar (not inclusive)
resolution: string
countback: number of bars (higher priority than from) starting with to. If countback is set, from should be ignored.

Example: GET `/history?symbol=BEAM~0&resolution=D&from=1386493512&to=1395133512&countback=500`

A response is expected to be an object with some properties listed below. Each property is treated as a table column, as described above.

```
s: status code. Expected values: ok | error | no_data
errmsg: Error message. Should be present only when s = 'error'
t: Bar time. Unix timestamp (UTC)
c: Closing price
o: Opening price (optional)
h: High price (optional)
l: Low price (optional)
v: Volume (optional)
nextTime: Time of the next bar if there is no data (status code is no_data) in the requested period (optional)
```

Notes:

Bar time for daily bars should be 00:00 UTC and is expected to be a trading day (not a day when the session starts). Charting Library aligns the time according to the Session from SymbolInfo.

Bar time for monthly bars should be 00:00 UTC and be the first trading day of the month.
Prices should be passed as numbers and not as strings in quotation marks.

Example:

```
{
   s: "ok",
   t: [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692],
   c: [42.1, 43.4, 44.3, 42.8]
}
{
   s: "no_data",
   nextTime: 1386493512
}
{
   s: "ok",
   t: [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692],
   c: [42.1, 43.4, 44.3, 42.8],
   o: [41.0, 42.9, 43.7, 44.5],
   h: [43.0, 44.1, 44.8, 44.5],
   l: [40.4, 42.1, 42.8, 42.3],
   v: [12000, 18500, 24000, 45000]
}
```

If it is possible, it would be better to handle the countback parameter for performance reasons. Basically, if you handle countback, you don't have to worry about passing next time, because countBack helps to avoid empty responses for ranges with no data.

**After these changes you can replace the `https://demo-feed-data.tradingview.com` by your API URL** in index.html